# SQL in version 6.5.4 in icCube

Tags: iccube

In version 6.5.4 of iccube reports, can SQL be used in the community version or is it in the enterprise version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your question is. But I will try to interpret your question in several ways and answer each of them...

1) in the community version you can use SQL as one of the datasources. Here you see the complete set:
[image: data sources available in the community edition]

2) As an example, here is my demo on projects working in the community edition: [image] You can use any SQL statement that is supported by the relational database you are using, or you can connect to tables or views directly.

3) Once, you have set-up, build and loaded your schema, you can drill-through to your SQL data. Here a simple example on a MySQL database:
[image: example of a drill-through interaction between a chart on a cube and a table based on a SQL query.] What is important, though, is that you have the "visibility" in your ETL datasource set to "reporting" (see previous image on the ETL part).

4) the main restriction in the community edition is that it is limited in memory and server options. See more on this on the [pricing and options page](https://www.iccube.com/prices/). But, the most important part is that the community can not be used for commercial purposes (see the end-user license aggreement, [EULA](https://www.iccube.com/eula/)).